# Can KVM run on Freescale IMX6 SABRE board?

Tags: linux-kvm, arm

I'm wondering if KVM can run on Freescale IMX6 SABRE board, which has ARM Cortex A9 processor?

I searched around but couldn't find any information about this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Looks like KVM has arm support in some cases has for a while https://lwn.net/Articles/557132/ I assume you want to run ARM VMs?

Comment: Yes, I want to run VM on ARM boards. Thanks for sharing the LWN articles. According to the article, "KVM/ARM is designed specifically to work on ARM processors with the virtualization extensions enabled to run unmodified guest operating systems." It means Cortex A9 is not supported. :-(